# How can I get code coverage data for iOS?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'd like to see code coverage data for an iOS project.

Apparently it used to be possible using gcov but using Xcode 4.5 does not result in any gcda files.

Do you know of any tutorials or solutions on how to get such data using the latest Xcode 4.5.1?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the following flags in your unit test target:

`Generate Test Coverage Files` and `Instrument Program Flow`

to `yes`.

As far as I remember there will only be coverage files if the unit test pass.
You will find the coverage files in `.../Derived Data/Your App/Intermediates/Your App.build/Objects-normal/i386`

Comment: Thanks, the critical information was to let the unit tests pass. 
Initially I tried to see how it works using an "endless loop" test that however never passed.

Answer (score 2):

I went to an excellent presentation on Code coverage in Xcode at our Regular London iOS Developer Group Meeting.

You can get the slides [from Lanyrd](http://lanyrd.com/2012/lidg44/sytpc/).

If I recall correctly, it's actually easier with the newer Xcode.

Comment: May I suggest writing a short summary of what is contained in the slides? Just incase for whatever reason that link dies one day.

Comment: I normally would - but the point of my answer was to look at the slides themselves. And in any case - I've got Richard's phone number, so I'll always know where those slides are :)

Comment: No they aren't. I just went to the linked page and was able to download them again.